# Dragon Naturally Speaking 10 enters bad characters in certain text editors in Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, microsoft-office, openoffice, dragon-naturally-speaking

I use DNS 10 in Win 7 without any problems for dictating in office XP and office 2007. I have installed it too on a computer under WinXP and there, with office XP and office 2003 it enters wrong characters instead of ê, è, à, ù, while it has no problems with é and ç.

For example, it writes
'voilŕ' for 'voilà, 'lŕ-bas' for 'là-bas', 'pčre' for 'père', 'męme' for 'même', 'oů ętes-vous' for 'où êtes-vous'.

This doesn't happen when I dictate here in the internet browser, nor in Wordpad, Notepad, or Open Office.

-- On the other hand, there are problems that appear only in OpenOffice and the internet browser: for example, when dictating a phrase like "Qu'est-ce qu'on peut faire?"("What can we do?) it appears as "quést-ce quón peut faire", while it is always put right in the other editors. --

Can I fix this? - or at least: What the cause might be?

Comment: This sounds more of a problem with Windows XP French language support then a problem with DNS 10 itself.  Have you installed the French language pack?

Comment: @Ramhound - yes. but you see issues vary according to the text editor

Comment: It sounds like the problems are caused by campatability problems with Windows XP. You have even clearly defined what the problem is to be honest. Sounds like plain old French language problems in Windows XP. **Why are you not contacting Nuance for support?**

Comment: @Ramhound Nuance support is notoriously most of the time useless.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - While they might be notoriously useless its a valid approach to solving this problem.  Of course I still suspect the problem is Windows XP and not Nuance's software itself.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a font related problem if it varies across applications. Try changing your fonts in the editor that it doesn't work it to one from an editor that does, and see if that affects the problem.

For the second problem, I believe that the editor automatically substitutes `'e` as `é` and `'o` as `ó` to make typing special characters easier. I don't have a copy of OpenOffice handy, but you should be able to turn off autocorrect somewhere in the preferences dialog.

Comment: wordpad was working with arial, so i have tried that in  msword but the same issue there. with all the fonts  i've tested wordpad works while msoffice does not. must be some problem with this DNS version in WinXP. considering the other issue (different in fact, as you noticed) - i will look for a setting to stop OO doing that automatically. normally i use US_international (with dead keys + Space key)  for the special characters and do not expect them to pop in like that