# Dragon Naturally Speaking 10 enters bad characters in MSOffice 2007 in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2007, dragon-naturally-speaking

I had [a similar problem](https://superuser.com/q/611813/162573) in Win XP, that I was not able to solve but now all of a sudden this happens in Windows 7 with MSOffice 2007.

What is most disconcerting is that this happens all of a sudden, while all the same software, DNS 10 and Microsoft office 2007 worked very well together until today.

What happens is that it writes 'voilŕ' for 'voilà, 'lŕ-bas' for 'là-bas', 'pčre' for 'père', 'męme' for 'même', 'oů ętes-vous' for 'où êtes-vous'.

This does **not** happen when I dictate here in the **internet browser**, in **Notepad, Wordpad or OpenOffice.**

Some new changes must have taken place that I cannot identify.

What type of changes could these be?

---

The problem seems to be with Office 2007. DNS displays the proper spelling in its floating box , while the error is inserted in the text editor:

[image]

---

Changing the font or reinstalling both applications doesn't help. I have installed Office 2003 and the problem is present there too.

Comment: It is off language for me, but your description and pictures indicate that the speech recognition itself is working, and the "correction" is being made by the program.  I would be seeking out the programs AutoCorrect (spelling) features, and disabling or altering it.

Comment: Try switching keyboard language between EN and FR. I know it sounds crazy but it actually does affect things not directly related to keyboard input.

Comment: thank you all for your comments - i suppose the bounty will expire, because i am on holliday and i will not be able to confirm any solution until expiration. but i will try what was suggested and also will test in a virtualbox installation - and then maybe i will figure out a solution

Answer (score 0):

It might occurred because the **DNS add in “dgnword.dll” has become disabled**.

try this :

Launch Microsoft Word 2007.

Click the Office button.

Choose **Word Options**.

Click **Add-ins**.

If **NatSpeak Word AddIn** (dgnword.dll) does not appear in the **Add-ins** list then it has been disabled.

Select **Disabled Items** from the **Manage** dropdown list, then click **Go**.

Highlight **dgnword.dll** in the **Disabled Items** list and click **Enable**.

Click **Close**, and then click **OK**.

Source : [nuance](http://nuance-community.custhelp.com/posts/0634e34f7b)

Comment: no addin in disabled list